# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction is not returning promise or promised event emiter

Tags: web3js, sendsignedtransaction

I am testing whether transactions that I'm signing offline are accepted by the Kovan network. I'm submitting the transactions using Web3.js (web3@1.20) as follows:

I connect to my Open Ethereum 3.0.1 node, and then use web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction. According to the documentation, this should return a PromiEvent. However, the events emitted by the submission are not captured and the promise never resolves. The transaction is submitted to the network nonetheless and is valid (it's a simple transaction sending funds from one non-contract account to another). One can find it in any blockexplorer, like for instance etherscan.

The code below does not behave as expected:

function sendTrans(_rawData,_txHash) {

```
    try {
            
            console.log("Before Asynch call");
                                    
              web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(_rawData)
                .once('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("txHash", hash) })
                .once('receipt', function(receipt){ console.log("receipt", receipt) })
                .on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ console.log("confNumber",confNumber,"receipt",receipt) })
                .on('error', function(error){ console.log("error", error) })
                .then(function(receipt){
                    console.log("trasaction mined!", receipt);
                });
                
          console.log("After Asynch Call");
         }
    catch (error) {
      
      console.log("Error Sending Transaction", error.message);
         
    }
      return { response: "OK", transHash: _txHash };
  }
```

// result: the code does not trigger any emitter event. No logging to the console is made.

The code above just hangs, because the promise returned by sendSignedTransaction is never resolved. No event is received either, so the .on('receipt') is never triggered. However the transaction is successfully submitted to the network and mined.
So the problem is not with the submission, but rather with the PromiEvent that web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction returns.

Anyone has any idea of why this behavior is happening?

Comment: Try `const promiEvent = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(_rawData)...` and then `console.log(promiEvent)` to ensure you get the right return object.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I took your advice. The promiEvent info is 

promiEvent Promise {
  <pending>,
  _events: Events <[Object: null prototype] {}> {
    transactionHash: EE { fn: [Function], context: [Circular], once: false }
  },
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners],
  _eventsCount: NaN
}
However, the eventEmitter still not firing.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa. All I want to do is get the transactionHash and return that to my client application. Let the transaction get broadcasted to the nodes, get picked up by a miner and then get mined. I can't wait around for 1+ minutes while the client app is blocked

Comment: Here is my PromiEvent + await code with Angular - known to be work https://gist.github.com/miohtama/a91a5edabac6bf66de860a444fc13206#file-transaction-helper-component-ts-L289 - I am hoping to release this as an open source library later, so hopefully you see if it is any different from your code.

Comment: transaction hash comes from the wallet within 1-2 seconds. I think your promise might not be never resolved, so that's why any of the handlers are not firing.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa. The only way I could get the event emitter to fire was to do the following:
 let promiEvent = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(_rawData)
                    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("txHash", hash); return { response: "OK", transHash: hash }; });
This did fire the .on(transactionHash) and get me the txHash. However, my code to return the json back to calling function did't work. Probably because it was still waiting for the Promise to complete (which is getting the transaction receipt from my ethereum node. I will still play around.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#id64):

```
// using the promise
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});


// using the event emitter
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    ...
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
    ...
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', console.error); // If a out of gas error, the second parameter is the receipt.
```

In your code, you seem to be attempting to use both the promise and the event emitter.

In addition to that, for the event emitter, you seem to be using `once` instead of `on`.

I'd start by fixing these two (getting rid of the `then`, and replacing `once` with `on`).

Comment: I am using web3.js with both `await` and `on` in the same `PromiEvent` object and it works correctly. Furthermore `once` is supported. This is directly from web3.js documentation itself: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/callbacks-promises-events.html#promievent

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: There's no `await` in the question, there is a combination of `then` and `on`, which to my understanding of the docs, is wrong (only one of them should be used).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa. I changed my code to the following. function sendTrans(_rawData,_txHash) {
        
        var respHash = "nothing";
        try {
                
                console.log("Before Asynch call");
                                        
                  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(_rawData)
                    .once('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("txHash", hash); respHash = hash; });
       The value of respHash was "nothing". The event emitter didh not fire for transactionHash. I will try your other suggestion next.

Comment: @goodvibration I took your advice, changed my code to the following

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(_rawData)
                    .on('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("txHash", hash); respHash = hash; });
Still not getting the event emitter to fire. 
All I want to accomplish is to immediately return the tx hash and then send that result back to my client DAPP. I can't wait for more than 30 seconds for Ethereum to process my transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` in a promise that will resolve when the transaction is calculated.

```
const hash = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
  await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx)
    .once('transactionHash', (hash) => {
      resolve(hash)
    })
  console.log('We\'ve finished')
})
console.log('Hash: ', hash)
```

Unfortunately due to https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3204  web3 will wait for confirmation (if some task is pending node will wait until it is finished so removing await will not fix it).

If you want to skip web3 confirmation you have to use the [eth_sendRawTransaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendrawtransaction) api and communicate directly with the provider's send (untested).

```
web3.currentProvider.send({
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
  params: ['0xf8648080....'],
  id: 253,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return reject(err)
  }
  return resolve(result)
})
```

Comment: I get it. That's why it is so hard to get users to on-board using an Ethereum blockchain. The user experience is so difficult to manage (like waiting for minutes until the transaction is mined and a receipt is created). To implement this for a user would require some sophisticated polling code.